# How to compare filed 1 and field 5 where field 1 and field 5 are numeric number

Tags: bash

I have question i have one csv file. I want to compare `filed 1` and `field 5` where `field 1` and `field 5` are numeric number.
If they matches then i should print `field 6`.
Date is in not in order. I tried with bash while loop but it display only matched content. My requirement is it should match all the and give the precise output.

```
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 
do
  if [[ $f1 -eq $f5 ]]
  then
     echo $f1 $f5 $f6
done < test.csv
```

Comment: please provide a small sample `test.csv` (with sample matching and non-matching data), the (wrong) output your script is generating, and the expected (correct) output

Comment: 567,RAKESH G,1-Jan-11,RECEIVED,123,01-Jan-12
345,SUNIL SHARMA,1-Jan-11,RECEIVED,345,03-Jan-12
123,Pavani,1-Jan-11,RECEIVED,567,05-Jan-12

Comment: you need to update the question with the additional details; most people are not going to scrounge through comments trying to piece together the details

Comment: Above is the sample data that i am trying to match.field-1 is 567 in first row which should match with field-5 of last row 567 and should display the field-6 which is date.

Comment: @kalyan, please put your sample data, expected output and current output in the body of your Q (then delete your comments). Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F"," '{if ($1 == $5) print $1,$5,$6}' < test.csv
```

Comment: I tried the above awk command but it displays 345 345 03-Jan-12. As they are match in the second row. Not sure what logic i should write to automatically search the value and match it and display the date which is last column. Any thoughts ?

Comment: This DOES answer your question as posed in your question above. Please improve your  question so that you don't have to come back with "one more thing". Again, if you had small sample input, expected output and current output, we'll be able to help.